# siunitx arcsecond invalid arcformat

Tags: siunitx

I couldn't find any information on why siunitx is giving me an error "invalid-arc-format" when I am trying to use

```
\arc{;60 }
```

for 60 arcminutes. It works fine for degrees and arcseconds as follows

```
\arc{60}
\arc{;;60}
```

Unless I just failed to read something in the manual, it should work right?

---

**Edit**

Here is code that compiles with no errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}
$\ang{60}$

$\ang{;;60}$

%$\ang{;60}$
\end{document}
```

This does not with error

> siunitx error: "invalid-arc-format", 
>    Invalid degree-minute-secondangle ';60'.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}
$\ang{60}$

$\ang{;;60}$

$\ang{;60}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution... I guess the

```
\arc{}
```

command needs a final placeholder to know where it is in the sequence of degrees, arcminutes, and arcseconds.

The solution to my problem is

```
\ang{;60;}
```